# Normal map bake problem with weird artifacts

Tags: materials, normal-map, artifacts

I was following this tutorial on how to bake a normal map https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LuEqvO9QsE
and the result is this
[image]

I even tried using the cage method and the result is pretty much the same. What's going on

Comment: hello, have you tried to change the Ray Distance? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I change the value of the ray distance many times yet the problem persists.

Comment: please share your file so that we can test  ;)

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ZwdJBS6y/

Answer (score 0):

Your scene is on metric unit and your shirt is very big (15.7 m height), so you'll need a high value of *Max Ray Distance*, give it for example 2. Also to have a better result I've used a 2048 X 2048 picture and an *Extrusion* value of 1 (not sure how it works though):

[image]

Comment: Hold up, how do you get the "extrusion" setting appear without enabling the "cage" option? Are you using version 2.9?

Comment: yes 2.9, I can't see it in 2.8

Comment: Looks like I have to move to 2.9 just to get the baking right.

Comment: perhaps, I had some problems with 2.8, I didn't know if it was me or Blender

Comment: Nvm, it's still the same. I f*cking fed up with this. I'd never had this problem with the previous version on two laptops I've used so far. I really don't know what causes this. I'm not sure whether my graphic card or CPU that borked up during baking process.

Comment: still the same with 2.9? you can also try with 2.79, it worked better than 2.8

Comment: Guess what? Using 2.79 version works as I wanted. Anyway, thank you.